# SQL Server : generate select statement dynamically inside a stored procedure with dynamic column names

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to generate a select statement inside a SQL Server stored procedure. I have the column names in SQL parameters.

I am trying to generate the select statement programatically with chosen column names, but can't seem to find correct syntax inside stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.aProc
     @testCondition int,
     @colCount int,
     @column_1 varchar(100) = null,
     ....
    @column_40 varchar(100) null
AS
  DECLARE @qry nvarchar(3000)
  DECLARE @Iterator int

  SET @testtype = 2
  SET @Iterator = 0
  SET @qry  ='SELECT '

  WHILE (@Iterator < @colCount-1)
    BEGIN
        SET @qry = @qry + ''+@column_''+CAST(@Iterator as varchar(2))+',''
        Set @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
    END


  SET @qry = @qry + ''@column_+CAST(@colCount as varchar(2)) FROM aTable where aCol = @testCondition
```

Comment: why do you need + '' + parts? you also have 2 quotes instead of one after colon. Can you explain what you trying to achieve in your proc?

Comment: i want to generate a SELECT stmnt based on what columns used wanted to see, so easiest way for me was to pass column names in sql para and based on them i generate the sql select stmnt dynamically in stored procedure.

Comment: well I'd say it's easier to change you proc signature, you can pass string like 'column1, column2, column3' and so on if you really sure you want to do this task

Comment: it has that signature already, i am trying to "build" the query string with minimal effort, lines of code, via a loop

Comment: Are you using Sql Server?

Comment: @Luv, Yes, MSSQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The Stack Overflow syntax highlighter already shows you the error: the string literal. SQL Server also tells you that with its message.

Comment: Is this to get around database architects forcing you to use stored procedures only? I think this is a very good lesson for these people. We'll find a way around your rules. You can't possible audit every one of our scripts. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bad idea ([obligatory sql injection link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)) with possible alternatives

To answer the question then do something like this.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + 
               ISNULL(@col1, '') + ', ' +
               ISNULL(@col2, '') + ', ' +
               ISNULL(@col3, '') + ', ' +
               ISNULL(@col4, '') + ', ' +
               ISNULL(@col5, '') + ', ' +
               -- ...
           'FROM tbl WHERE ' ...
```

It's less effort doing it this way - or perhaps as the comments have suggested - than messing around with loops (which btw you are well off the mark for).

To be honest though you would seem to be better off using an inline function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.vSomeTable
    (@id INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE condition = @id
)
```

and then let user do

```
SELECT col1, col2, col2 FROM dbo.vSomeTable(4)
```

which is nicer than

```
EXEC dbo.aProc @condition=1, @col1='col1', @col2='col2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.aProc
    @tablename varchar(100),
     @testCondition int,
     @colCount int,
     @column_1 varchar(100) = '',
     ....
    @column_40 varchar(100) ''
AS
BEGIN
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null
drop table #t


select 
table_name
,column_name
into #t
from information_schema.columns
where table_name=@tablename
and column_name in 
(@column_1,@column_2,@column_3,@column_4,@column_5
.....
@column_36,@column_37,@column_38,@column_39,@column_40)

select 
  'select '+
  stuff((
    select ', ' + 'isnull('+t2.column_name+','''') as' +t2.column_name+CHAR(10)
    from #t t2
    where t2.table_name = #t.table_name
    for xml path (''))
,1,2,'')+' from ' +#t.table_name
from #t
group by #t.table_name

END
```

I am not a great admirer of **LOOP**. In fact i hate loop Queries.